# Error running gulp-sass after update to Node v4.0.0

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-sass, node-sass

I updated to Node v4.0.0 and after when I run gulp in my projects I get an error with regards to gulp-sass/node-sass, as follows:

> Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?

I've tried trashing all the node modules in the project and reinstalling, and I get some errors:

> npm WARN package.json package@0.0.0 No repository field.
>
> npm WARN package.json package@0.0.0 No license field.
>
> npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as 'css-select'
>
> npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
>
> npm WARN deprecated pangyp@2.3.2: use node-gyp@3+, it does all the things
>
> -
>
> node-sass@2.1.1 install /Users/Jonathan/Documents/sites/wkux/ct-html-lib/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
>
> node scripts/install.js
>
> Can not download file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sass/node-sass-binaries/v2.1.1/darwin-x64-node-4.0/binding.node
>
> node-sass@2.1.1 postinstall /Users/Jonathan/Documents/sites/wkux/ct-html-lib/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
>
> node scripts/build.js
>
> gyp: /Users/Jonathan/.node-gyp/4.0.0/common.gypi not found (cwd: /Users/Jonathan/Documents/sites/wkux/ct-html-lib/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass) while reading includes of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
>
> gyp ERR! configure error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/Jonathan/Documents/sites/wkux/ct-html-lib/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/pangyp/lib/configure.js:346:16)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
>
> gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
>
> gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/Jonathan/Documents/sites/wkux/ct-html-lib/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/pangyp/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
>
> gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Jonathan/Documents/sites/wkux/ct-html-lib/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
>
> gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
>
> gyp ERR! pangyp -v v2.3.2
>
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> Build failed

All the other node modules seem to have installed fine. Its something with node-sass thats in gulp-sass that is causing issues.

Comment: In package.json, what version does it list for gulp-sass?

Comment: "gulp-sass": "^1.1.0",

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Delete your node_modules folder, update `gulp-sass` to the latest in your package.json, which is `2.2.0`, and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Made my day, all the answers I found were "install python" and I just couldn't believe it. Thanks!

Comment: BOOOOM!! It works. I can't believe I overlooked version numbers in package.json. Thanks @Yuri

Comment: The package.json installed fine with Node 0.12.0 on another machine. I was running Node 4.0.0. Following the above steps fixed the issue.