# Cannot installing sass in ionic. Using node v4.2.1

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

Whenever I try to setup sass in ionic I get the following error

```
Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
```

I tried to rebuild sass as mentioned in many forums but get no results. I'm using node v4.2.1

Comment: You have to have the ruby gem `sass` installed. Make sure you got ruby with `ruby -v`, if you don't, you can install it with RVM `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`. Then run `gem install sass`. Take close note to the RVM installation, it will tell you what to do.

Comment: Found the solution here!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594885/error-running-gulp-sass-after-update-to-node-v4-0-0

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed problems with libsass or node-sass with this command:

```
$ sudo rm -rf node_modules/ && cat package.json | sed -i.bak 's/"gulp-sass": "^X.X.X"/"gulp-sass": "^2.0.4"/g' package.json && npm install && ionic lib update
```

Where X is the version of gulp-sass in your package.json

**Explanation:**

Remove the old files in node_modules. I'm not sure is necessary to use 'sudo' (in my case, yes).

```
$ sudo rm -rf node_modules/
```

---

Search and replace inside package.json updating gulp-sass version to ^2.0.4. It also creates a backup (package.json.bak),

```
$ cat package.json | sed -i.bak 's/"gulp-sass": "^X.X.X"/"gulp-sass": "^2.0.4"/g' package.json
```

---

Reinstall dependencies

```
$ npm install
```

---

Update the ionic lib in the project

```
ionic lib update
```

If you have any further problems be sure I try can help you...

Bye